# Thread Busy apache tomcat decompress data

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I have and application deployed in tomcat and have a lot of thread busy with no release more than 700 thead like this.

I captured the thead dump the file is on [ufile.io/8zz1t](http://ufile.io/8zz1t) , and i use [fastthread.io](http://fastthread.io) to read. Can you check if you see the problem, I see that the inflater have the thread with cpu consume.

```
S   188063346 ms    0 KB    0 KB    10.162.3.36 172.30.100.163  POST /ChiperService/rest/cs/Descifrar HTTP/1.1
S   280064346 ms    0 KB    0 KB    10.162.3.36 172.30.100.163  POST /ChiperService/rest/cs/Descifrar HTTP/1.1
S   185431144 ms    0 KB    0 KB    10.162.38.201   172.30.100.163  POST /ChiperService/rest/cs/Descifrar HTTP/1.1
S   267094596 ms    0 KB    0 KB    10.162.3.36 172.30.100.163  POST /ChiperService/rest/cs/Descifrar HTTP/1.1
S   261396699 ms    0 KB    0 KB    10.162.3.36 172.30.100.163  POST /ChiperService/rest/cs/Descifrar HTTP/1.1
```

What part of this code can cause the thread busy? I don'´t know if the deflater or inflater have to be close.

In the tomcat manager for the app ChiperService there are not active sessions.

Please help the server is crashing almost 5 time in the day becouse the thead busy and the high cpu consume.

This is the rest service:

```
package ChiperServicePkg;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import principal.allus.com.co.SBCCypherModuleMain;
/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author 1017200731
 */
@Path("/cs")
public class CiphersResource {

@Context ResourceConfig Config;

/**
 * Creates a new instance of CiphersResource
 */
public CiphersResource() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param UUI
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@POST
@Path("Cifrar")    
public String Cifrar(String UUI) throws Exception 
{
    String Key = (String) Config.getProperty("KeyCipher");
    String dataEncrypted = null;
    try
    {
        dataEncrypted= SBCCypherModuleMain.cifrar(UUI,Key );            
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex instanceof IOException){
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }
        else{
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
    return dataEncrypted;
}

/**
 *
 * @param dataEncrypted
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@POST
@Path("Descifrar")
public Response Descifrar(String dataEncrypted) throws Exception
{
    String Key = (String) Config.getProperty("KeyCipher");
    String dataDecrypted= "";
    
    try
    {
        dataDecrypted= SBCCypherModuleMain.descifrar(dataEncrypted, Key);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {            
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
    }
    return Response.ok(dataDecrypted).build();
}  

/**
 * Sub-resource locator method for {id}
 */
@Path("{id}")
public CipherResource getCipherResource(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return CipherResource.getInstance(id);
}
```

}

The method Descifrar call a jar provide by the client and with a decompiler I can extract the following code:

```
  public static String descifrar(String bytes, String llave)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, Exception
  {
    byte[] vector = null;
    String retorno = "";
    
    retorno = SBCCypherModuleCompress.descomprimir(SBCCypherModuleCypher.descifrar(bytes, llave.substring(0, 16)));
    
    return retorno;
  }
```

The SBCCypherModuleCompress class is the following:

```
 public class SBCCypherModuleCompress
{
  public static String comprimir(byte[] data)
    throws IOException, Exception
  {
BASE64Encoder b64e = new BASE64Encoder();
    
    byte[] output = null;
    String salida = "";
    
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    deflater.finish();
    
    byte[] buffer = new byte['?'];
    while (!deflater.finished())
    {
      int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    
    salida = b64e.encode(output);
    
    return salida;
  }
  
  public static String descomprimir(String data)
    throws DataFormatException, IOException, Exception
  {
    BASE64Encoder b64e = new BASE64Encoder();
    BASE64Decoder b64d = new BASE64Decoder();
    
    byte[] output = null;
    String salida = "";
    byte[] datad = null;
    
    datad = b64d.decodeBuffer(data);
    
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    
    inflater.setInput(datad);
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(datad.length);
    
    byte[] buffer = new byte['?'];
    while (!inflater.finished())
    {
      int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    
    output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    
    salida = b64e.encode(output);
    
    return new String(output);
  }
}
```

The SBCCypherModuleCypher class is the following:

```
public class SBCCypherModuleCypher
{
  public static String cifrar(String vector, String llaveSimetrica)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, Exception
  {
    BASE64Encoder b64e = new BASE64Encoder();
    BASE64Decoder b64d = new BASE64Decoder();
    
    byte[] datad = null;
    String salida = "";
    
    datad = b64d.decodeBuffer(vector);
    
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(llaveSimetrica.getBytes(), "AES");
    
    byte[] campoCifrado = null;
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(1, key);
    campoCifrado = cipher.doFinal(datad);
    
    salida = b64e.encode(campoCifrado);
    
    return salida;
  }
  
  public static String descifrar(String vector, String llaveSimetrica)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, Exception
  {
    BASE64Encoder b64e = new BASE64Encoder();
    BASE64Decoder b64d = new BASE64Decoder();
    
    byte[] datad = null;
    String salida = "";
    
    datad = b64d.decodeBuffer(vector);
    
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(llaveSimetrica.getBytes(), "AES");
    
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    
    cipher.init(2, key);
    
    byte[] datosDecifrados = cipher.doFinal(datad);
    
    salida = b64e.encode(datosDecifrados);
    
    return salida;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try a thread dump to see if all threads are at the same running point. I would bet on `while (!inflater.finished())` but I don't what is the Inflater object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how can i use the thread dump ??  thanks in advance

Comment: `kill -3 PID` if you're running on Linux. On windows, it's more complicated (see [RedHat - Java thread dump on Windows](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19170) for example)

Comment: I'm running on linux , i going to check and let you know

Comment: what's is better ? or have less high procces {jstack pid} or {kill -3 pid} ? and if i use {kill -3 pid} where is the output ?

Comment: by default it's in catalina.out. If you have 700 threads running, there will be thousands of lines.

Comment: also you can add "%D" parametr to "server.xml" for logging - Time taken to process the request (see documentation on: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html)  and after tomcat server restart you will see response time(in milliseconds) for every request in localhost_access_log.{date}.txt file. it may help to find slowly running request.

Comment: @AlekseiKurepin I upvote, although a restart is required. In fact, a good config helps later debug.

Comment: Hi Guys!! i captured the thead dump the file is on https://ufile.io/8zz1t , and i use http://fastthread.io to read. Can you check if you see the problem, i see that the inflater have the thread with cpu consume.

Comment: On the line `count = inflater.inflate(buffer);` check that count is not zero, otherwise you get infinite loop.

Comment: The buffer that is being passed into the `inflater` looks strange: `byte[] buffer = new byte['?'];` - the `'?'` is the size, so a buffer of 63 bytes once the char has been converted to an int.  A much larger buffer is generally a good idea for performance, e.g. `new byte[65536]` or even megabytes depending on what's being decompressed.

Comment: in the thread dump only ~15 threads are at Inflater code, others are just waiting for work to arrive. You do not have 700 hundred threads busy. How big are the String, byte[] that are being encoded? What is the memory usage? Is it crashing because of OOM? Do a verbose GC log and review the same.

Answer (score 1):

All your threads are in `inflater.inflate(buffer)` in SBCCypherModuleCompress.java, line 92.

But why have you written `new byte['?']` ? That's in the following code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte['?'];
while (!deflater.finished())
{
  int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
  outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

and also in the following code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte['?'];
while (!inflater.finished())
{
  int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
  outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

`new byte['?']` makes no sense.

`new byte[2048]` or perhaps `new byte[8192]` would be better instead of `new byte['?']`.